# Send data from jQuery AJAX to ASP.NET in Phonegap application

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, cordova

I have a fully operational ASP.NET Webform application (.aspx) that sends and retrieves data to the server (CodeBehind) using jQuery AJAX. For my next project I need to recreate this application but with Phonegap to make it mobile and platform independent.

I'm trying to use the same CodeBehind file that handles the database connection and all the needed methods to make the application work.

```
// File-structure

Application
    App_Code
    pages
        Default.aspx (with codebehind)
        phonegapapp
            www
            - index.html (with jquery AJAX calls)
    ...
```

From the index.html file I'm trying to make a connection to the Default.aspx.cs file to access the necessary functions:

```
// phonegapapp/www/index.html

$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        ...
        url: "../../Default.aspx/testFunction",
        // tried with only one ../ and going to root and follow file structure but non is working.
        ...
    });
});
```

I get an error showing that the file is not found:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Application/pages/Default.aspx.cs/testFunction. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
```

Comment: You really shouldn't use pages or web/page methods for this. You should use [ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api). Or if you want to go minimal, use generic handlers (.ashx) or custom handlers. Basically, your web server should expose an endpoint and your page should communicate with that endpoint via AJAX. Pages (.aspx) don't need to be involved. Probably a good idea to split the server side and client side into separate projects too, as it appears you're trying to use .aspx pages on the client.

Comment: Are you trying to load ASP files from your phonegap project?

Comment: Also, you can't use relative paths to reference the exposed endpoints, because the endpoints will be on the server. You'll need a full URL, something like `https://example.com/customer/1`. It's best to embed the page URL into your configuration on the client, then when you construct URL's for calls to the server, you combine the base URL with the path to the resource you want to retrieve. `var BaseURL='https://example.com'; $.ajax({url: BaseURL+'/customer/'+customerId})` or something along those lines.

Comment: Thanks, I added a Web Api to my App_Code folder. How can I send and retrieve data from it using jQuery AJAX in .html file? Looks like I cannot reach it with just typing the path in the jQuery url attribute. If you give it as an answer I'll surely upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

You cant execute/access aspx files wihtin phonegap app. Simply you have to put your aspx files behind an Asp.Net supporting webserver such as IS and then you load call ajax with relative path, like http://localhost/default.aspx and then you will be able to get the response.